# Point releases vs milestone releases in Yocto

Tags: yocto

There are different type of releases in Yocto project

- Major Release
- Minor Release
- Point Release
- Milestone Release

Can anyone explain the difference between these all releases, which release should a developer pick up for their hardware platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me quote the [official documentation](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Yocto_Project_Release_Process), since it answers it quite well:

> Major release number changes imply compatibility changes with previous releases. Minor release number changes imply significant changes up to, but not including compatibility changes. Minor rev number changes are for minor issues such as simple bugfixes, security updates, etc.

This is basically the popular [semver versioning scheme](https://semver.org/)

And for milestone releases we have:

> These releases are performed at the end of a milestone period and are used to measure our progress in delivering new features to Yocto Linux.

More info on the milestones can be found [here](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Yocto_Project_Design_and_Development_Process#Milestone_Releases)

When it comes to which version to choose it's something that you need to do based on the demands of the project. Basically I'd say you would either choose the latest [LTS release](https://www.yoctoproject.org/yocto-project-long-term-support-announced/) or the latest release. You might also want to keep using the latest during the early development phase, to later settle on an LTS release to maximize the amount of time the release will be supported after it's complete.

Comment: Before releasing a major version, there will be milestone releases for that version correct?

Comment: @md.jamal I see the milestones as something project internal related to how they divide the work up between releases. I don't think they do a last milestone release just before a new major release, but I'm not sure.

Comment: They write that "Feature complete/freeze before stabilization weeks of the last milestone: after this point, no new features or functionality should be added into the release.".

Comment: Point release are what the called "Minor rev number" in the text I quoted above. It's described in the official documentation I linked: "minor rev release number (aka "point" or "patch" release)"